# What is the best way to store access token in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Well, this is a pretty simple question as it's described by the title.

So my services are all deployed on AWS.  This access token is for consuming other services.  And, so far, I have `mysql` already deployed, and I can also use `S3`.  Which one would be better?  Is there any better way doing this?

Comment: How about neither?  Store your access token locally, not in the cloud, in a safe place, or, better yet, multiple safe places.

Comment: @Tim-Biegeleisen we assume the question is - how could aws services be authorized to use different aws services. At the end, the client needs aws credentials to invoke any aws api service. Or custom credentials to connect to rds.

Comment: @gusto2 I thought the OP was asking about where to store the initial access key, which you need to connect to your instance via SSH.  I think this key should just be stored locally, because if in the cloud and somehow it gets stolen, you're out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "access token"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use either:

- Secrets Manager: https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/ (see pricing first)
- SSM Parameter Store, using encrypted string.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using service-linked roles where possible

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html

This way you may allow one resource using another without explicitly storing cerentials.

If you really need some system credentials, then the system parameter store (as already suggested in another answer) seems feasible solution

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in multiple ways just make sure it is protected and encrypted.

As mentioned above Secrets Manager make most sense if you are in AWS.
I  have some doubts about using s3 for secrets. DB could also be a storage it really depends on your use case.